# How to calculate the angle of reflection of a ball bouncing of an angled surface

Tags: javascript, html, math, physics, angle

I've been trying to create a pure javascript version of the "plinko" game. I don't have a maths or physics background so everything I've picked up has been from google/youtube.

**I'm trying to calculate the angle a ball should bounce at when making contact with an angled surface.** I've got as far as calculating the angle of the ball at impact and the angle of the line its making contact with using **inverse tan** and the **velocity x and y of the ball and line** respectively. I then found the angle of incidence by finding the difference in the two angles, which according to snell's law should give me the angle of reflection relative to the line it has impacted.

However, having implemented this in code (or at least I think I have) the angles calculated and the direction of travel of the ball does not make sense. Here is the section of the code that deals with that:

```
           var lineVelX = startPos[0] - endPos[0];
           var lineVelY = startPos[1] - endPos[1];

           var lineAngle = Math.atan(lineVelY / lineVelX) * 180 / Math.PI;

           var ballAngle = Math.atan(window[ball].velY / window[ball].velX) * 180 / Math.PI;

           var angleOfIncidence = ballAngle - lineAngle;

           var newBallAngle = ballAngle - angleOfIncidence;


           window[ball].velX = Math.cos(newBallAngle) * 2;
           window[ball].velY = Math.sin(newBallAngle) * 2;
```

Hopefully, someone with a greater understanding of maths and physics can explain where I'm going wrong.

[Here is a link to my code in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/majorhints/hq1sd0xp/1/).

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: [How do I include code for jsfiddle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358212/how-do-i-include-code-for-jsfiddle)

Comment: I would start by using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval` and introducing the concept of "delta time" so that you can properly perform your calculations. Clearly the collision detection is a bit off.

Comment: I'd recommend using vectors instead of angles. The discontinuity of polar coordinates at 360° (or ±180°) makes life a little harder, and so does the divergence of `tan` at odd multiples of 90°.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I'd been working with vectors before but I had run into issues, as I'm not entirely sure how to use an incidence vector to calculate the refection vector. Would you be able to explain how to do it or know of any guides I could follow? What form should the vectors take? for example (velx, vely) or (direction,magnitude)

Comment: By "vectors" I meant Cartesian vectors (as opposed to `[direction, magnitude]` which is the polar representation you are already using). Take a look at [this Mathexchange page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13261/how-to-get-a-reflection-vector)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Thanks for the link!

Comment: A picture would be *really* helpful.